# How to use Dictionary instead of list in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to use dictionary to store text present on boxes in column rather than using list. there are lots of boxes in column number of boxes changes depending on option selected

```
${text_List}=  Create List #1st list
FOR  ${list}  IN RANGE  3  ${element_count}+1 #count depends on element present but it will be same as ${total_list_count} below
  ${list_text}=  Get Text  ${xpath}${list}
  Append To List   ${text_List}  ${list_text}
END
#expected output= ['124', '1445', '1123', '456', '2354'] 

FOR  ${element}  IN RANGE  1  ${total_list_count}+1 #list count is same as  ${text_List} 1st list count
  @{Text_List}  Create List
  ${web_elements}=  Get WebElements   ${xpath}
  FOR ${ele}  IN  ${web_elements}
      ${element_txt}=  Get Text  ${ele}
       Append To List  ${Text_List}   ${element_txt}
   END
END
```

I want ${text_List} to be used as key and ${Text_List} to be  used as value dont want to use any list

I tried by using

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example Test Case
${text_dict}= Create Dictionary # Create an empty dictionary named ${text_dict}
FOR ${list} IN RANGE 3 ${element_count}+1
${list_text}= Get Text ${xpath}${list} # Get the text value of the ${list} element
Set To Dictionary ${text_dict} ${list_text} ${EMPTY} # Add the text value as key to the dictionary with an empty value
END

FOR  ${element}  IN RANGE  1  ${total_list_count}+1  # Loop through a range of values which is same as the count of elements in ${text_dict}
    ${web_elements}=  Get WebElements  ${xpath}  # Get a list of web elements using an xpath expression
    FOR ${ele}  IN  ${web_elements}  # Loop through the web elements
        ${element_txt}=  Get Text  ${ele}  # Get the text value of the web element
        ${key}=  Get From Dictionary  ${text_dict}  ${element}  # Get the key value from ${text_dict} using ${element} as index
        Set To Dictionary  ${text_dict}  ${key}  ${element_txt}  # Set the value of the key in ${text_dict} with ${element_txt}
    END
END
```

But got error as Tried with above code but got error as Dictionary does not contain key ‘1’

to get expected output as

```
{'124': 'for loop text one by one for that column', '1445': 'for loop text one by one for next column', '1223': 'for loop text one by one for that next column', '456': 'for loop text one by one for that next column', '2354': 'for loop text one by one for that next column'}
```